# Responsive Design - Div disappearing

Tags: css

This is a website : http://advancedcomputerdiagnostics.dcdev1.com

The div `.top-bar` disappears at 830px. Does anyone have ideas as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is disappearing because of this in your css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px)
.masthead .top-bar, .masthead .hide-on-mobile {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Consider removing it, or changing the design approach if you want it to stay visible.

Comment: I cannot see this media query when I inspect the element

Comment: You have to decrease the page's width for the console to pick it up. It's likely in a completely different file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a media query CSS rule that is set to hide that element in this file `http://advancedcomputerdiagnostics.dcdev1.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-less/dt-the7/css/media-bad99586e5.css?ver=3.1.0`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {

  .masthead .top-bar,
  .masthead .hide-on-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }

}
```

Comment: I cannot see this media query when I inspect the element